# print text on my R plots

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

I am having a hard time to print text on my R plots.

I have 3 plots, and for each of them I would like to add a label (p-value).
Then for each of the 5 values that allowed me to draw a curve, print the value on the graphic.

In fact I would like to make my figure looks like the following figure (see bellow).

Using my following script.

Any help?
Thanks in advance,
Best,

```
df <-  structure(list(lowerA = c(4.1, 4.6, 5.5, 4.7, 5), Group1 = c(4.8,5.4, 6.4, 5.5, 5.7), 
                      upperA = c(5.7, 6.3, 7.3, 6.3, 6.6), lowerB = c(6.2, 7.1, 8.7, 7.4, 8.2), 
                      Group2 = c(7.3, 8.3, 10, 8.6, 9.5), upperB = c(8.6, 9.6, 11.4, 9.9, 10.8), 
                      lowerC = c(18.3, 19.5, 24.3, 22.9, 25.5), Group3 = c(21.4, 22.5, 27.6, 26.3, 29), 
                      upperC = c(24.7, 25.8, 31, 29.8, 32.7)), 
                 .Names = c("lowerA", "Group1", "upperA", "lowerB","Group2", "upperB", "lowerC", "Group3", "upperC"), 
                 row.names = c("year1", "year2", "year3", "year4", "year5"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

class(df)
df <- as.data.frame(df)

#### Data Base

colnames(df) <- gsub("A","1",colnames(df))
colnames(df) <- gsub("B","2",colnames(df))
colnames(df) <- gsub("C","3",colnames(df))

colors <- c("#000099", "#CC0000", "#808080")
labels <- c("red line", "black line","black line")

#########
lablist<-as.vector(c("2010","2011","2012","2013","2014"))
axis(1, labels = FALSE)

#########

library(scales)
plot(df$Group1, type = "n",ylim = c(0,40),frame.plot = FALSE, main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "Survival at hospital discharge (%)",labels = FALSE)
axis(1, at=1:5, labels=c("2011-2012","2012-2013","2013-2014","2014-2015","2015-2016")) 
axis(2, at=c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40), labels=c("0","10","20","30","40")) 


for(i in 1:3){
  lines(df[,paste0("Group",i)], col = colors[i])

  polygon(x = c(1:nrow(df),nrow(df):1),
          y = c(df[,paste0("lower",i)],rev(df[,paste0("upper",i)])),
          col = alpha(c("white","white","white"), 0.1),
          # si tu veux garder les couleur des IC le long des courbes mets commande si après:
          # col = alpha(colors[i], 0.1),
          border = NA)

  arrows(x0 = c(1:nrow(df)),
         x1 = c(1:nrow(df)),
         y0 = df[,paste0("lower",i)],
         y1 = df[,paste0("upper",i)],
         col = colors[i],
         angle = 90,
         length = 0.05,
         code = 3)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `text()` to plot text. You may want too first plot the lines, then plot white points to serve as a background for the text, and finally plot the text on top.

Comment: how would you do that Gregor? with my data frame? I tried but It won't work... Thanks

Comment: The scales package is part of the ggplot2 universe. I have serious doubts that it should be used with base plot functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example getting the point labels. I'll leave the P value labels as an exercise for the reader.

```
plot(df$Group1, type = "n",ylim = c(0,40),frame.plot = FALSE, main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "Survival at hospital discharge (%)", axes = F)
axis(1, at=1:5, labels=c("2011-2012","2012-2013","2013-2014","2014-2015","2015-2016")) 
axis(2, at=c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40)) 

for(i in 1:3){
  lines(df[,paste0("Group",i)], col = colors[i])

  arrows(x0 = c(1:nrow(df)),
         x1 = c(1:nrow(df)),
         y0 = df[,paste0("lower",i)],
         y1 = df[,paste0("upper",i)],
         col = colors[i],
         angle = 90,
         length = 0.05,
         code = 3)

  points(df[,paste0("Group",i)], col = "white", pch = 15, cex = 2)
  text(df[,paste0("Group",i)], labels = df[,paste0("Group",i)], col = colors[i], cex = 0.7)      
}
```

I set `axes = F` instead of `labels = F` in `plot()` to get rid of the warning, and I deleted the `polygon` code because it wasn't doing anything. You may want to further adjust the `cex` of the text and the points so it is sized nicely.

[image]

Comment: Niceee ! Thanks Gregor ! Actually the hardest part is now to add the "P=" on each curve -as on the first figure.. Any idea? Best,

Comment: It's basically the same. You can use `paste()` to stick `"P = "` on your labels. As I said in the answer, I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Yes sure !  By defining the vector `p1 <- c("1","2","3")` and adding `text(p[i], labels = p1[i], cex = 0.9) ` it prints the values but never at the right place. how would you specify the right place? thanks.

Comment: Specify the x and y coordinates where you want it to go. See `?text` for help.

Comment: Oh thats what I actually did meanwhile but out of the loop separately ! and it works perfectly ! Thanks again.